# How to solve equations involving the sum of special exponential functions?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, exponential-function, special-functions

I am studying equations of the form

$f_1 e^{g_1z}+f_2e^{g_2z}=f_3e^{g_3z}$

where the $f$'s and $g$'s are functions of the form $ax+by$, with $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$.  I'm interested in things like

$2xe^{2xz}+4ye^{(3x+y)z}=(2x+4y)e^{yz}$

I feel like there should be a straightforward way to solve/simplify this given that $e$ in there, but I can't figure it out.  Maybe I'm missing something simple.  Or can equations like this really be solved only via numerical means?  Are there some advanced techniques I could consider to get an analytic solution (in terms of x, y, z)?

Thank you

Comment: In some cases, you can do something like a substitution $x'=e^x$ or just apply the log to both sides of the equation and solve it, but in this case, you have a [transcendental equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_equation), so no can do.

Comment: What is (are) the unknowns ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Apologies.  X, y, z unknown.

Comment: @DoobieMath: check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $z$ is your unknown, even

$$e^{5z}+e^z+1=0$$ can't be solved analytically (it is equivalent to $t^5+t+1=0$).

If $x$ is your unknown, even

$$xe^x=1$$ cannot be solved, but with the help of Lambert's $W$ special function.

There is no hope of an analytic solution in the general case, this equation family is "highly" transcendental.

Comment: Thanks, @Yves Daoust--accepted.  What if we weren't interested in solutions, but proving inequalities of this sort?  Any appropriate techniques there?